# How to enable Google Cloud Secret Manager audit logging via Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a Google Cloud project with secrets stored in Secret Manager. I want to [audit Secret Manager data access](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/audit-logging). I want to enable this auditing via Terraform, as opposed to clicking around in the UI. How do I do that?

Comment: Logs regarding Secret Manager data access are controlled by Audit Logging. I am not aware of a Terraform Data Source to enable **data access audit logs**.